# Unable to reach Tomcat server through AppWorks OpenText mobile application

Tags: opentext, cordys-opentext

I deployed a sample app to my OpenText Tomcat server. In the Opentext console of the sample app, the gateway url is set as my local IP address and port is 8080. Installed the opentext android app and iphone app available in playstore and appstore in the respective devices and put the gateway url (My IP address with port number) in the hostname field of the app but it says "Unable to access the server".

On putting the system IP address in my phones browser is working but through app it says "Unable to access the server".